# Math/Physics Circuit Problem from CAP contest involving Resistance

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

Consider a circuit made of a wire with uniform resistance
in a shape of a circle as shown in the picture. The
circle is connected diagonally from point A to point B
with the same type of wire. If the current passing
through the circuit is i0, what is the current passing
through the wire AB as a function of angle θ?
[image]

Comment: Did you try applying Kirchoff laws? Should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: Why will it even depend on $\theta$?

Comment: @UddeshyaSingh Consider $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$. The wire is as good as nonexistent (there is no current through it). Now consider $\theta=0$.

Comment: You can adapt the solution to the problem from [here](http://www.resistorguide.com/kirchhoff-law/). Tell us whether or not you succeed.

Comment: If an answer addresses your question in a satisfactory manner, it is customary to accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excuse the clumsy 'artwork':

Without loss of generality we can take the resistance per unit length to be one and we can take the radius to be one.

One approach is to use  [Norton's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norton%27s_theorem). (a) shows the general
circuit and (b) shows how the current splits between two resistors.

(c) Shows how the Norton equivalent resistance is computed and (d)
shows how the Norton short circuit current is computed (with the aid of
(b)).

(e) Shows the Norton equivalent circuit and from this (again with the aid of
(b)) shows that
$i_D = {1 \over 1 + {4 \over \pi}}(1-{2 \theta \over \pi}) i_0$.

[image]

Another approach would be to perform a $\Delta-Y$ conversion on the three rightmost resistors in (a).